# How to get callback function when file uploads using multer in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, multer

In multer https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer how do I check when a file uploaded? Where can I access the callback function for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You specify a callback in the `fileFilter` option (see https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter) when initializing multer that will be called for every file uploaded, or you can simply check the `req.file` (if you use `.single()`) or check `req.files` if you use `.multi()` in the express callback.

e.g.:

```
const multer  = require('multer');
const upload = multer({
    dest: 'upload/',
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log('fileFilterCallback', file);
        cb(null, true);
    }
});
app.post('/upload', upload.single('recfile'), function (req,res) {
    console.log('express callback', req.file);

})
```

Hope this helps.